# What is the meaning of this symbol ">>" in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I found this example and i can't understand the result :

```
$x = 5;
echo $x>>2;
```

output :

```
1
```

Can you explained for me please
Thanks

Comment: [php:operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) explains it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a >> $b    Shift right     Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the right (each step means "divide by two")

So if 5 in binary is: **101**

5>>1 is 2 in binary **10**

5>>2 is 1 in binary **1**

This operator if common in other languages such as C.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)